# Firebase security rules issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to restrict access to a particular groups if the user is not in the members list.

So this is my rule,

```
{
  "rules": {
           ".read":"auth != null",
    "groups": {
      "$groupid":{
          ".read" : true,
          ".write" : "root.child('groupmembers').child($groupid).child('admins').child(root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('username').val()).val()==true"
      }

    },
    "groupchat":{
      "$chatid":{

          ".read" : "root.child('groupmembers').child($chatid).child('members').child(root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('username').val()).val()==true",
          ".write" : "root.child('groupmembers').child($chatid).child('members').child(root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('username').val()).val()==true"

    }

  }
  }
}
```

The first rule for `"groups"`>`"$groupid"` works perfectly.  But I'm getting problem with second rule for `"groupchat"`

DataStructure ex:

**Group Chat structure**

```
"groupchat" : {

      "testinggroup" : {
        "chat" : {
              "-KiYN6RKZOyWI-qufWn3" : {
              "message" : "Hey",
              "timestamp" : 1493094660399,
              "type" : "text",
              "username" : "user2"
             }
           },
        "lasttimestamp" : 1493094660674
  }

}
```

**Users Structure**

```
"users":{
  "ujciTL9oFKNylcgiGcdYqUxjcgA3" : {
    "email" : "example@gmail.com",
    "username" : "user1"
  }
}
```

**groupmembers structure**

```
"groupmembers":{
  "groupid":{
    {
      "admins" : {
        "user1" : true,
        "user3" : true
      },
      "members" : {
        "user1" : true,
        "user2" : true,
        "user3" : true,
        "user4" : true
      }
    }
}
}
```

**groups structure**

```
"groupid"{
{
  "category" : "group category",
  "creator" : "creator uid",
  "desc" : "group desc",
  "id" : "groupid",
  "image" : "url",
  "name" : "groupname"
}
}
```

Operation ex:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("groupchat")
                .child(j)
                .child("lasttimestamp")
                .setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

So to debug the errors

I added "myusername" in place of `root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('username').val()`
and it's working.

But in the previous rule("For `groups` child") I added the same thing and it was working.

I don't know why I'm getting error.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code for an operation that is failing?

Comment: sure wait a seconf @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Added a example...

Comment: Hmmm... and what's the **minimal** JSON (you can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data)) that must be already present to reproduce this with?

Comment: i didn't completely understand ur question.(May be bcoz of my weak english) I guessed you may want the json example. So I added that to my code :$ @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Is the user listed in groupmembers/$groupId/members as well as in groupmembers/$groupId/admins ?

Comment: Yeah the user is a part of admins and members node @VelkoIvanov

Comment: I don't see a problem with the rules - if one works, the other two will work too, there must be some problem in the data, or the way you test. Are you sure you write to "groupchat" with the same user that writes to "groups" for example ? You are most likely missing some minor detail, but we can't really see what it is from the data you provided - it doesn't show us the whole picture. This is why Frank above asked you to provide the whole DB structure that is relevant to the problem - including "groupmembers", "users", "groups" (but in a minimal fashion - excluding repetitions or private data)

Comment: Ohk lemme add @VelkoIvanov

Comment: added the json strcuture @VelkoIvanov

Comment: So can anyone give me the solution for it? This rule is important for my project :(

Comment: I tried some other rules, the problem is with auth.uid . It's not working everywhere for me. I replaced it with the uid i'm using right now and it's working.. @FrankvanPuffelen